# I am trying to sum each parameter with a value, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: function, lambda, functional-programming, scheme

I am basically new to Scheme, and this is my second attempt to solve a certain problem.

So what I am trying to do basically is sum each parameter we pass into the function, with an appropriate value
for example:

```
 (sum 3 1 2 0 2) ;would return 228
```

Here is my code:

```
(define  (sum one five ten twenty fifty hundred)
    (+ (* 1 one)(* 5 five) (* 10 ten) (* twenty 20) (* 50 fifty) (* 100 hundred))
```

I think a possible solution is using the lambda function, but I could't know how to implement it.

Comment: 1. You do not use commas for separating arguments to a function call. You use spaces. 2. You are missing either a `twenty` or `fifty` argument. Your function call, thus, should be `(sum 3 1 2 0 0 2)`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young edited and corrected.

Comment: My second point has still not been corrected. Your function takes 6 parameters but you only passed 5 arguments.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Can i skip an argument i don't want to use? Is there any way I pass 5 arguments instead of 6 like i did?

Comment: In your specific case, you really should make your function take keyword (named) arguments. Lemme write an answer to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: you have two problems: in your `define`, the closing parenthesis is missing; in the call, one argument is missing, as Chris has told you. correct both things, and it'll work. so basically, what you wrote was alright, except for the two typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can calculate the numbers by sending in only 5 arguments instead of 6:

```
(define sum
    (lambda (L skip) ;stores yourList and the number you want to skip
       (define loop
          (lambda (L L2 total) ;yourList, (1,5,10...) list, running total
             (cond
               ((null? L) (list total)) ;print the total when finish yourList

               ;if the next number is the skip number, just move on to next value
               ((= (car L2) skip) (loop L (cdr L2) total)) 

               ;otherwise, increase total and send in both lists, minus the head, to the loop
               (else (loop (cdr L) (cdr L2) (+ total (* (car L) (car L2)) ))) 
              )
           )
        )(loop L (list 1 5 10 20 50 100) 0) ;initial values of loop
    )
)

;send in your list of numbers, plus the value place you want to skip
(sum (list 3 1 2 0 2) 20) ; ==> 228
```

I would be much easier, though, to just fill in all the places that you don't want with a 0. Once you have 6 arguments, the following code will work.

```
(define sum
    (lambda (one five ten twenty fifty hundred)
        (+ (* 1 one) (* 5 five) (* 10 ten) (* 20 twenty) (* 50 fifty) (* 100 hundred) )
    )
)

(sum 3 1 2 0 0 2)
```

Comment: Not the simplest solution, but definitely solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The OP wants to be able to pass fewer arguments than there are parameters. In this specific case, it's best to use keyword (named) arguments. Here's how you might do this (in Racket syntax):

```
(define (total-bills #:ones (ones 0)
                     #:fives (fives 0)
                     #:tens (tens 0)
                     #:twenties (twenties 0)
                     #:fifties (fifties 0)
                     #:hundreds (hundreds 0))
  (+ ones (* fives 5) (* tens 10) (* twenties 20) (* fifties 50) (* hundreds 100)))
```

(The `0` after each of the variable names are the default values, that is, what the value would be if you don't specify it.)

Example usage:

```
> (total-bills #:ones 3 #:fives 1 #:tens 2 #:hundreds 2)
228
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea,But how do we write it in plain old scheme?

Comment: Standard Scheme does not have optional parameters.

Comment: What about optional arguments? here is an example: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html

Comment: You could use optional arguments using dotted tail notation: `(define (sum . args) (apply + (map * args '(1 5 10 20 50 100))))`.  In some Schemes you may need to load SRFI-1 so that map stops when the shortest of its argument lists is exhausted.

Comment: @Predator44 The syntax described in the page you linked to is available only on Racket, as well as Scheme implementations that provide [SRFI 89](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-89/srfi-89.html). But it's not part of the Scheme standards.

Comment: @sjamaan I like your idea, but it doesn't quite pertain to the OP's case where they want to omit arguments in the middle. :-( (Oh, and small world! I always enjoyed reading your IRC messages.)

Comment: @chris-jester-young You're right of course.  However, I was replying how to use optional arguments to do this, which inherently doesn't allow for omitting arguments in the middle. You can only omit arguments at the end. There's no standardized way to have named arguments (though there are a few SRFIs and DSSSL, which CHICKEN implements)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use standard scheme with a similar scheme as [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30092808/1565698) in plain old Scheme you need to plan how to identify which currency your number is in. Perhaps by sending them in pairs would be both simpler to implement and simpler to use:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(define (total-bills . args)
  (fold-left (lambda (acc x)
               (+ acc (apply * x)))
             0
             args))

(total-bills '(5 1) '(2 10) '(3 100)) ; ==> 325
(apply total-bills '((1 3) (5 1) (10 1) (20 2))) ; ==> 58
```

You can make a procedure that makes a specialized procedure based on currencies you pass to it:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(define (make-currency-procedure . currencies)
  (lambda amounts
    (fold-left (lambda (acc currency amount)
                 (+ acc (* currency amount)))
               0
               currencies
               amounts)))

(define small-bills (make-currency-procedure 1 5 10 20))
(define large-bills (make-currency-procedure 10 100 1000 10000))

(small-bills 3 1 1 2) ; ==> 58
(small-bills 0 1 0 1) ; ==> 25
(large-bills 3 1 1 2) ; ==> 21130
(large-bills 0 1 0 1) ; ==> 10100
```

Comment: But why do we have small-bills and large bills? Can't we combine them both into one function?

Comment: @Predator44 Yes. You can make a procedure with any combination, **but** all the currencies you define in it becomes required in the order you define them. To have something similar to Chris' optional input the first example is a better approach.